# how to make a "fancy" report of what my unit tests are doing

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit.net

I'm looking for a way to generate some sort of report that describes what kind of unit tests we are making, for non-technical people. Something similar to the view you can get in the test explorer, where you can group tests by traits and give them simple names, e.g.

[[image: test explorer extract1]

all the reporting tools I seem to be finding are related to code coverage and it all seems to boil down to this tool https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator
we are looking for something that can be integrated to devops and that could generate an html report as an artefact for instance, that would be available as part of the build.

Comment: Have you taken a look at coverlet? It's a NuGet package you add to your project and along with a .NET CLI tool you can generate the reports and publish them to your build server. I wrote a blog post about testing in az devops but should help with other CI providers: https://blog.joaograssi.com/asp-net-core-integration-tests-with-docker-compose-azure-pipelines/. The post contains a link to the GitHub repo. Here is a test run: https://joaopgrassi.visualstudio.com/BlogApp/_build/results?buildId=46&view=codecoverage-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet). I'll try to layout how you can get it working on azure devops:

1. Add the Coverlet package to your Test project: (it might be there already if you created a xunit test project)

```xml
<PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

2. Then for your build pipeline in Az Devops, you need some steps:

- Install the report generator .NET CLI tool (the one you referred to)**

```yaml
# will install the tool locally at the current path
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: tool
      arguments: install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
```

Then, after you are done building your project, you need to **1. test**, **2. create the reports** and finally, **3. publish them to az devops**:

```yaml
# instruct dotnet test to collect code coverage from your tests
# https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet#usage
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Test
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: 'tests/**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"'

# uses the reportgenerator dotnet tool to generate the Cobertura report type
  - script: ./reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.TempDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(coverageReportDir) -reporttypes:"Cobertura"
    displayName: Create coverage reports

# publishes the Cobertura report to az devops
  - task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
    displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
    inputs:
      codeCoverageTool: Cobertura
      summaryFileLocation: $(coverageReportDir)/Cobertura.xml
```

If all is well, after a successful build you should see this in az devops:
[image]

Clicking on it, will take you to the report with the breakdown of coverage:

[image]

And you can even drill-down to individual files and see the line coverage there: (not sure for you but that does look fancy to me!)
[image]

I wrote a blog post about integration tests in Azure DevOps where I (indirectly) talk about this subject. You can check it on my blog here: [ASP.NET Core integration tests with docker-compose on Azure Pipelines](https://blog.joaograssi.com/asp-net-core-integration-tests-with-docker-compose-azure-pipelines/)

You can check the full code (tests and the az devops yaml pipeline) on [GitHub](https://github.com/joaopgrassi/dockercompose-azdevops/blob/main/az-devops/blogapp-pipeline.yaml)

And finally you can see a test run by yourself here: https://joaopgrassi.visualstudio.com/BlogApp/_build/results?buildId=46&view=codecoverage-tab

** I installed the .NET tool on a path and not globally because I had issues with the tool not being set in the PATH variable after installing it: Here's a GitHub issue with some discussion about it: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8291

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That's for code coverage though isn't it? I'm looking for something that allows me to display in a more user friendly manner and in a somewhat summarized version (as opposed to listing every single unit testing method) what tests are we performing. Our project manager asked for that so that he can get an idea of what tests we are running and maybe come up with new test cases

Comment: Coverlet generates coverage reports, and you can feed them to reportgenerator to obtain a lot of different views. If none of out-of-the-box report output format suits your needs, you can create your own: https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator/wiki/Custom-reports. But IMHO I'm a bit confused about it being not friendly. The link I showed shows a summary of lines covered, be it via unit tests or integration tests, and it's optional to dig into each file/coverage/line. The summary is already there in a normal "table".  Maybe try showing this format and see what they say first?